# Does new char actually guarantee aligned memory for a class type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is allocating a buffer via `new char[sizeof(T)]` guaranteed to allocate memory which is properly aligned for the type `T`, where all members of `T` has their natural, implementation defined, alignment (that is, you have not used the `alignas` keyword to modify their alignment).

I have seen this guarantee made in a few answers around here but I'm not entirely clear how the standard arrives at this guarantee.  5.3.4-10 of the standard gives the basic requirement: essentially `new char[]` must be aligned to `max_align_t`.

What I'm missing is the bit which says `alignof(T)` will always be a valid alignment with a maximum value of `max_align_t`. I mean, it seems obvious, but must the resulting alignment of a structure be at most `max_align_t`? Even point 3.11-3 says extended alignments may be supported, so may the compiler decide on its own a class is an over-aligned type?

Comment: Finally, a good question.  Can I upvote a whole bunch of times? (CLICK CLICK CLICK)

Comment: @JohnDibling: by yourself, no, but there's a bunch of us fortunately :D

Comment: Not an answer, but can't you just play it safe and use `new T` and cast the result? Oh, and +1 for teaching me a new tag. I never heard about language-lawyer.

Comment: What the spec says about `sizeof` must be relevant too: 5.3.3-2 says "When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for
placing objects of that type in an array"

Comment: I still don't understand the question.

Comment: There is a note in `[basic.align]/3` -- `[note every over-aligned type is or contains a class type to which extended alignment applies (possibly through a non-static data member) end note]`. I can't find the normative reference for this, but it seems to imply that your T will never be over-aligned.

Comment: @Mankarse: looks like it actually answers the question then. Even though it seems quite hand-wavy, I have not found better :x

Comment: @Mankarse, let's assume the note is normative. But does it somehow forbid the compiler from applying an extended alignment on its own?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I thought it did, but on a rereading I realise that it actually doesn't...

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I think it is the intention, however the **is** is quite weird. Also inheritance is not clearly featured... it's a weird quote, definitely, but it is the *only* quote in the standard which seems to actually attempt to defined what `over-aligned` means !!

Comment: There is also another note which seems to explicitly allow this `[expr.new]/10` -- `[ Note: Because allocation functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental alignment, this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed. — end note ]`. [continued...]

Comment: That said -- the normative text still requires an object with a fundamental alignment requirement, and there does not seem to be anything that states that `alignas` is the only way in which over-aligned types can be created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I'm missing is the bit which says `alignof(T)` will always be a valid alignment with a maximum value of `max_align_t`. I mean, it seems obvious, but must the resulting alignment of a structure be at most `max_align_t` ? Even point 3.11-3 says extended alignments may be supported, so may the compiler decide on its own a class is an over-aligned type ?

As noted by Mankarse, the best quote I could get is from **[basic.align]/3**:

> A type having an extended alignment requirement is an over-aligned type. [ Note:
>   every over-aligned type is or contains a class type to which extended alignment applies (possibly through a non-static data member). —end note ]

which seems to imply that extended alignment must be explicitly required (and then propagates) but cannot

I would have prefer a clearer mention; the intent is obvious for a compiler-writer, and any other behavior would be insane, still...

Comment: It uses the word _applied_, could a compiler apply an extended alignment on its own? Or do points 1/2 in the paragraph to imply that any alignment applied by the compiler must be at most `max_align_t`?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: **[dcl.align]/1** also uses the verb apply: "An alignment-specifier may be applied to", so I would *expect* that this means that it is where the applies come from and it should be explicitly required but...

Answer (score 18):

The expressions `new char[N]` and `new unsigned char[N]` are guaranteed
to return memory sufficiently aligned for any object.  See §5.3.4/10
"[...] For arrays of char and unsigned char, the difference between the
result of the new-expression and the address returned by the allocation
function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental
alignment requirement (3.11) of any object type whose size is no greater
than the size of the array being created. [ Note: Because allocation
functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is
appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental
alignment, this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the
common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other
types will later be placed. —end note ]".

From a stylistic point of view, of course: if what you want is to allocate raw
memory, it's clearer to say so: `operator new(N)`.  Conceptually,
`new char[N]` creates `N` `char`; `operator new(N)` allocates `N` bytes.

Comment: It's only required to provide alignment for a type with a fundamental alignment requirement, up to `max_align_t`. so the question is whether the compiler may create class types of extended alignment, which would thus not be fundamentally aligned.

Comment: What does this answer add? The standards quote is the same section is referenced in the question.