# Is there any safe way to derive the offset of a T inside a std::optional<T>?

Tags: c++, stl, stdoptional, addressof

Given a `std::optional<T>` is it possible to derive the address of the `std::optional<T>` from the address of the `T`?

possible implementation:

```
template<typename T>
struct myoptional
{       static std::size_t getOffset(void)
        {       static const myoptional<T> s(std::inplace());
                return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&s.value())
                       - reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&s);
        };
};
```

Comment: What does adress of T mean? T is a type.

Comment: `std::optional<int> i = 5; auto ao = &i; auto ai = &*i;`

Comment: Even if you get this offset, in practice there is probably nothing useful you can do with this information. This is likely a XY problem. You should ask about the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about your attempted solution.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis the address of the object of type T, presumably?   what else could it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is not specified where exactly in its storage `std::optional` stores the object. If you assume that the location of the object is always the same for the same type `T`, you can maybe (see below) use the shown method to obtain an offset through the object representation.

However, even if you knew the offset of the object, you would still not be able to obtain a usable pointer to the `std::optional<T>` from a pointer to the `T` object. You would need to `std::launder` the resulting pointer to make it usable, which will only be allowed if `sizeof(std::optional<T>) <= sizeof(T)`, which seems unlikely/impossible. (Otherwise it would make previously unreachable bytes reachable in the meaning of the term *reachable* as in the preconditions for `std::launder`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)

---

Whether or not the use of the `reinterpret_cast` and the pointer arithmetic is allowed by the standard is not clear at the moment. The standard has some unresolved defects in that regard.

What you can do alternatively though and (as far as I can tell) shouldn't have undefined behavior is to use a `union` of a `std::optional<T>` with a `unsigned char[sizeof(std::optional<T>)]` and instead of using a pointer difference, you can then use addition and pointer comparison in a loop to find the offset in the character array matching the address of the `T` value. See e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647627/17732522).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If `sizeof(std::optional<T>) > sizeof(T)` then the pointer to the `T` object will not be able to reach some bytes in the storage occupied by the `std::optional<T>` object. Therefore trying to get from a `T*` to a `std::optional<T>*` will be impossible. (This is the direction OP is asking about in the question body.)

Comment: The question of pointer arithmetic on object representation is a current language defect. The intention is that it should be allowed but the wording does not actually support it yet.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well, it can't be smaller because it is specified to provide storage inside itself for the `T` object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I hope I addressed your comments in the answer. Regarding the object representation, it is not so clear to me whether it is supposed to work in this way. The problem is that if the shown casts were allowed and resulted in pointers to elements of the same array (the object representation of the `std::optional<T>` object), which is necessary for the pointer arithmetic to be allowed, then this cast would effectively circumvent the `std::launder` reachability requirement. You would always be able to just cast to `char*`/`unsigned char*` first.