# Calculate member offset of a packed struct (from a type list)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071840/9363996) shows how to calculate an offset of a type from a type list (`std::tuple`) taking alignment into an account.
**I would like to know if there's a way to also consider whether a pod structure that contains the types (members) does not use a standard alignment (i.e. `#pragma pack`ed).**

Here's a function that correctly calculates offsets of a non-packed structure, but fails to do so otherwise.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

template <typename /*CRTP*/>
struct calc_offset;

template <template <size_t> class ElemTraits>
struct calc_offset<ElemTraits<0>>
{
    constexpr static size_t value = 0;
};

template <template <size_t> class ElemTraits, size_t Index>
struct calc_offset<ElemTraits<Index>>
{
    constexpr static size_t _get_value() noexcept {
        constexpr auto roundUp = [](size_t num, size_t multiple) -> size_t {
            const size_t mod = num % multiple;
            return mod == 0 ? num : num + multiple - mod;
        };

        using prev_traits = ElemTraits<Index - 1>;

        const size_t type_alignment = std::alignment_of<typename ElemTraits<Index>::value_type>::value,
            prev_type_size = sizeof(typename prev_traits::value_type),
            prev_offset = prev_traits::offset;

        return roundUp(prev_offset + prev_type_size, type_alignment);
    }

    constexpr static size_t value = _get_value();
};

// not a real structure
template <typename POD, typename Fields>
struct pod_traits
{
    template <size_t I>
    struct element
    {
        using value_type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Fields>;
        using pod_type = POD;
        constexpr static size_t offset = calc_offset<element<I>>::value;
    };
};

struct normal
{
    uint8_t _0;
    uint64_t _1;
    uint8_t _2;
    uint16_t _3;
};

using normal_types = std::tuple<decltype(normal{}._0),
                                decltype(normal{}._1),
                                decltype(normal{}._2),
                                decltype(normal{}._3)>;
using normal_traits = pod_traits<normal, normal_types>;

static_assert(offsetof(normal, _0) == normal_traits::element<0>::offset);
static_assert(offsetof(normal, _1) == normal_traits::element<1>::offset);
static_assert(offsetof(normal, _2) == normal_traits::element<2>::offset);
static_assert(offsetof(normal, _3) == normal_traits::element<3>::offset);

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct packed_1
{
    uint8_t _0;
    uint64_t _1;
    uint8_t _2;
    uint16_t _3;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

using packed_1_types = std::tuple<decltype(packed_1{}._0),
                                decltype(packed_1{}._1),
                                decltype(packed_1{}._2),
                                decltype(packed_1{}._3)>;
using packed_1_traits = pod_traits<packed_1, packed_1_types>;

static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _0) == packed_1_traits::element<0>::offset);

// these fail
// static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _1) == packed_1_traits::element<1>::offset);
// static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _2) == packed_1_traits::element<2>::offset);
// static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _3) == packed_1_traits::element<3>::offset);
```

---

A wild guess, but it fixed the assertions `roundUp(prev_offset + prev_type_size, std::min(type_alignment, pod_alignment))`:

```
        const size_t type_alignment = std::alignment_of<typename ElemTraits<Index>::value_type>::value,
            prev_type_size = sizeof(typename prev_traits::value_type),
            prev_offset = prev_traits::offset,
            pod_alignment = std::alignment_of<typename ElemTraits<Index>::pod_type>::value;

        return roundUp(prev_offset + prev_type_size, std::min(type_alignment, pod_alignment));
```

Comment: The answer you link to calculates offsets by rounding values of `sizeof` to `alignas`.  As a first cut, if you know `#pragma pack` is in play, don't do that rounding up.   More significant problem is that the effect of a `#pragma` is implementation-defined - so no standard way to detect it is in play (e.g.  does it affect results from `alignas`?), its effect *can* vary between implementations, and what happens with mixing it (e.g. a not packed struct contains a packed struct).  There is no standard way to detect it - so the programmer needs to make an *assumption*.

Comment: @Peter I can't know if `#pragma pack` is in play. I assume it might be. One way would be to `static_assert` and restrict packed pods in the first place.

Comment: @Peter On the other hand, packing is used in many places for binary protocols (we will get into details here). The fact it is not standard does not guarantee in practice that the behavior will be different. The only way to be sure is to have lots of unit tests for each compiler and its version.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `#prama` directive is by definition [implementation-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl), there is no standard way to compute the struct layout using just the type information.

As a practical matter, however, you can probably compute the layout assuming the compiler inserts no padding by using the `sizeof` of each type in the tuple. The following code implements `calc_packed_offset` which is simpler than the version dealing with alignment.

```cpp
template <class>
struct calc_packed_offset;

template <template <size_t> class ElemTraits>
struct calc_packed_offset<ElemTraits<0>>
{
    constexpr static size_t value = 0;
};

template <template <size_t> class ElemTraits, size_t Index>
struct calc_packed_offset<ElemTraits<Index>>
{
    using prev_traits = ElemTraits<Index - 1>;

    constexpr static size_t value =
        sizeof(typename prev_traits::value_type) + prev_traits::packed_offset;
};
```

Adding this definition to `pod_traits`,

```cpp
template <typename POD, typename Fields>
struct pod_traits
{
    template <size_t I>
    struct element
    {
        using value_type = std::tuple_element_t<I, Fields>;
        using pod_type = POD;
        constexpr static size_t offset = calc_offset<element<I>>::value;
        constexpr static size_t packed_offset = calc_packed_offset<element<I>>::value;
    };
};
```

These assertions now hold,

```cpp
static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _0) == packed_1_traits::element<0>::packed_offset);
static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _1) == packed_1_traits::element<1>::packed_offset);
static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _2) == packed_1_traits::element<2>::packed_offset);
static_assert(offsetof(packed_1, _3) == packed_1_traits::element<3>::packed_offset);
```

Comment: Compiler will add padding depending on the argument used for packing (1, 2, 4, 8, 16). And more over it is a traits template function. The whole purpose is to find out whether to use a "regular" offset or a "packed" offset. It must be deduced automatically. Or packed structs should be restricted all together